# How to create Cross Platform .net core library?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-core, coreclr

How do i create C# library in .Net core that can be shared between classic .Net 4.6.2 and .Net core projects using Nuget packages. I read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries) about developing cross platform libraries. So i setup my project.json as below

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    },
    "net462": {          
    }
  }
}
```

Then i created nugect pckage by executing the following command

```
   dotnet pack -c Release
```

and then published the nuget package. My package name is DTO.

In my traget .net core project i was able to install nuget package without any issue. However when i try to install package in classic .net 4.6.2 project i get error

> install-Package : Could not install package 'DTO 1.0.0'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:1 + Install-Package DTO + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId
>   :
>   NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Note that the nuget package is hosted on my local server.

Comment: Two notes: why you need to target the `net462` extra. .NET Framework 4.6.2 is able to load `netstandard1.5` and lower. I highly doubt you need 1.6.  Lower is better. Second note: can you give us a look into the unzipped nuget?

Comment: @Thomas why 1.6 is better than 1.5?

Comment: You can find more info [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md)

Comment: Take JSON.NET as a sample. They target netstandard1.0. Why? Because netstandard1.0 is implemented by all frameworks (like .NET Framework 4.5, Silverlight, Xamarin, ...). netstandard1.6 is not even implemented by .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

You took the right direction. If you want compatibility across multiple frameworks, targeting .NET Standard is the right move.

However, you should refer to this matrix for the .NET Standard versions supported by each framework.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms

According to this table, **.NET Framework 4.6.2 supports .NET Standard 1.5** (not 1.6 as you specified). So here is your answer.

For more details about the assemblies supported in .NET Standard 1.5, please follow this link:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#list-of-net-corefx-apis-and-their-associated-net-platform-standard-version